# Powershell loops for syslog management

Tags: powershell, archive, syslog

If I run the script below it will perform all the tasks that I need it to. I need the task to run every 15 seconds in a loop. When I add a loop of any type, the loop gets stuck on only a portion of the script an no longer functions as expected. I'm looking to loop the entire script top to bottom. The current script does not have any loops at this time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Syslog Management. Automate has a max size of 977KB before it dumps everything into a file called Syslogold.txt
# If Syslogold.txt already exists it will be overwriten and logs will be gone.
# Script below will move syslogold.txt into syslog folder where it will be renamed to Syslog-(CurrentDate).TxT
# When ever a new Syslogold.txt is generated by Automate, this script will append the output to a daily file in a monthly folder.
# On the first day of every month, the previous month will be zipped and archived. 
#
$LastMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMM-yyyy')
$CurrentSyslogFolder = "C:\Windows\LTsvc\Syslogs\Syslogs-$(Get-Date -Format "MMM-yyyy")"
$OldDirectory = "C:\Windows\LTsvc\Syslogs\Syslogs-$LastMonth"
$CurrentLog = "Syslog-$(Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy").txt"
$OldLog = "C:\Windows\LTSvc\syslogold.txt"
$SyslogArchive = "C:\Windows\LTSvc\Syslogs\Archive\Syslog-$LastMonth.zip"

do{
$TestPath01 = Test-Path -Path $CurrentSyslogFolder
$TestPath02 = Test-Path -Path $CurrentSyslogFolder\$CurrentLog
$TestPath03 = Test-Path -Path $OldLog
$TestPath04 = Test-Path -Path $OldDirectory

if($TestPath01)
    {
    write-host "Syslog directory current."
    }
else
    {
    write-host "Current syslog directory is for last month. Creating new folder."
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $CurrentSyslogFolder
    }
if(($TestPath02) -and ($TestPath03))
    {
    write-host "Automate syslog archive found"
    write-host "Daily syslog Found."
    write-host "Appending Automate archive with daily syslog"
    Add-Content -Path $CurrentSyslogFolder\$CurrentLog -Value ""
    Get-Content -Path $OldLog | Add-Content -Path $CurrentSyslogFolder\$CurrentLog
    Remove-Item -Path $OldLog
    start-sleep -Seconds 15
    }
else
    {
    write-host "Automate syslogs active."
    write-host "Waiting for Automate to archive syslogs."
    if ($TestPath03)
    {
    Write-Host "Automate has completed archiving Syslogs." 
    Write-Host "Moving archive to daily syslog."
    Write-host "Daily syslog missing. Creating daily syslog now"
    Move-Item $OldLog -Destination $CurrentSyslogFolder\$CurrentLog
    }
    }
if($TestPath04)
    {
    write-host "Last months directory found."
    Write-Host "Compressing last months directory"
    Compress-Archive -Path "$OldDirectory" -DestinationPath "$SyslogArchive"
    Write-host "Moving compressed directory to archive"
    Write-host "Cleaning up files"
    Remove-Item -Path "$SyslogDirectory\Syslogs-$LastMonth" -Recurse
    Write-host "Cleanup completed"
    start-sleep -Seconds 15
    }
else
    {
    Write-host "Will try again in 15 seconds"
    start-sleep -Seconds 15
    }
}until($infinity)
```

Comment: The order in which you create the variables is wrong. You cannot for instance use `$LastMonth` **before** you actually give it a value. PowerShell works from top-of-script to bottom, so always start using variables **after** you have defined them. In this case, start the script with the definition of `$LastMonth` and move all `$TestPathxx` lines below the rest.

Comment: I have modified the script to show both suggestions. I'm still faced with the same issue. what ever is matched ( IF and ELSE ) from the first run will continue to hold those values. when the environment changes even though (ELSE) is now a match it is still processing it as (IF) when looped.

Comment: No, in variable `$OldDirectory` you use `$LastMonth` which is only defined **after** that. Please take care of the order in which you define and later user variables.. As I said earlier, _start the script with the definition of $LastMonth_

Comment: Also, move the `$TestPathxx` **inside** the do loop, so they get refreshed on each iteration.

Comment: My apologies I missed that. Thank you for correcting me again. I have updated the posted script. After modifying the script I still face the same Issue. If I run the script once it works perfectly. If I add a loop what ever was detected (IF or ELSE) will continue to be (IF or ELSE). If (if) was detected but when the environment changes (ELSE) will now match. But during the loop its still processed as an (IF).

Comment: Testing....If I run the script with out the monthly folder.  The script will create it. this matches (ELSE). I will stop the script. Then run the script again. it is now detected as and (IF) and not do anything since the folder is there. leaving the script running in a loop I will delete the monthly folder. It should now be detected as (ELSE) and create the folder but continues to be processed as (IF) and does nothing.

Comment: I have moved $TestPath inside do. Need a min to correct and respond.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this script. Your suggestions have helped me greatly. If you would be so kind to write your suggestions as an answer I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Will do, but I'm on mobile now, so this may take a while.. ;)

Comment: On second thoughts, since all it took was rearranging the parts where you define your variables, I encourage you to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.) this one. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the best way would be Scheduled Task [ScheduledTask](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler)
But you can also use do or [while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while?view=powershell-7.1)

`do{ YOURSCRIPT start-sleep -Seconds 15 }until($infinity)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have used what was provided and I still have the same issue. When in a loop what every statement matched the first time is what its doing every time. If (if) was matched and the environment changes which should now match against (else) it still processes (if).